# Errores de PHP en archivo

Tags: php

Estoy creando una aplicación en PHP, la duda que tengo es como puedo guardar los errores de sintaxis u otros que me genera la aplicación, así como el log de errores que genera apache pero que sea solo de una aplicación o un script especifico.

En mi script habilite los errores y cuando hay alguno si los muestra pero en pantalla, lo que quiero es guardar esos errores en un .txt o .log para posteriormente revisarlo.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
?>
```

Comment: Conviene saber que `ini_set()` **cambia la configuración de tu entorno PHP**. Yo te recomendaría que, si no lo has hecho, configures adecuadamente tu entorno desde el archivo `php.ini`. Allí puedes indicar lo que sería el comportamiento por defecto que te interesa, que suele ser precisamente escribir los mensajes de error en un log y no mostrarlos en pantalla. Luego, en aquellos contextos donde quieras ver errores en pantalla lo configuras poniendo algo así más o menos: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` Así los errores en ese script se mostrarán en pantalla.

Comment: @A.Cedano el punto no es ver los errores en pantalla sino guardarlos en archivo distinto al que genera apache, donde solo contengas los errores que genera mi aplicación. Agregue `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` solo para revisar si hay errores o no

Comment: Entiendo. Si quieres que los logs de errores se guarden en un determinado archivo, puedes poner algo así: `ini_set('error_log', 'ruta/errors.log');`  donde `ruta` sería una ruta válida en tu entorno. Como ya dije, si quieres que todos los logs de error vayan a ese archivo, puedes definirlo en `php.ini` como configuración global. Porque PHP tiene por lo general su propia forma de guardar los logs de errors, por ejemplo, creando un error_log en cada carpeta donde ocurre algún error. Si centralizas todo en un mismo archivo convendría guardar una traza completa  de los errores.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser con `error_log` y usando try-catch

```
<?php
    try 
    {
        $resultado = 4 / 0; //Operación para generar el error
    } catch (Exception $e) {   
        error_log("Error en división por cero." . PHP_EOL, 3, "errores.log");
    }
?>
```

Tambien puedes usar `set_error_handler`
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler

Comment: Pero seria un try-catch a todo el script o como? boy a revisar el set_error_handler